# How can I stream to a single YouTube channel, from multiple remote locations?

Tags: youtube

We want to do talk show live streamed to youtube where participants are in different geographical locations. We are looking for a software that allows us to split the screen between participants while showing a presentation on the background.

Now I know poeple are going to suggest Google's Hangouts on Air, and I know Hangouts on Air can do something like that but we are looking for a high quality live stream that can presrve the image and audio quality, just like a 'normal' live stream, except with multiple participants. Do you have any solution?

Thanks

Comment: How many participants are you talking about?  If you only want two participants, something simple can be hacked to do the job.  If you want 8 participants, you will need a more sophisticated setup.